# Measuring change in concentration of hydrogen peroxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, kinetics

I am conducting an experiment to find the rate constant of the decomposition of hydrogen peroxide, $\ce{H2O2}.$ For this, I was planning on using the integrated rate law:

$$\ln(\text{final concentration}) = -kt + \ln(\text{initial concentration})$$

However, I am not sure how I can measure the change in the concentration of $\ce{H2O2}.$ I would appreciate it if someone can propose a method.

Comment: Typically you measure the volume of evolved O2.

Comment: After that, what should I do?

Comment: Then calculate the concentration of H2O2 from these data.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to work with liquid, you could do titrations by sampling the solution over time. http://www.titrations.info/permanganate-titration-hydrogen-peroxide